# php-java-bridge

Tags: php, java, tomcat

Крутится значит файловый сервер оwncloud написанный на php. Доступен по url `http://localhost/owncloud` И есть томкат в котором есть веб приложение Доступно оно по url  `http://localhost:8080` Реально ли с помощью JavaBridge настроить томкат чтоб отображать owncloud  у себя по url   `http://localhost:8080/owncloud` ? 
Я как понял нужно устанавливать owncloud в tomcat

Comment: Можно по адресу `http://localhost:8080/owncloud` задеплоить сервлет, который будет проксировать запросы в `http://localhost/owncloud`. JavaBridge - это несколько другое. Это RPC для вызова кода на стороне Tomcat из PHP.

Comment: а вот по поводу проксирования, есть примеры как можно это реализовать в контроллере?